# How can i get data-itemvalue out of my div class?

Tags: jquery

How can i get data-itemvalue out of my div class, when it is selected?

i tried with a jquery option with a jQuery('#giftcardwrapping').val(); but with no luck

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span6">
      <div class="btn btn-flat btn-block giftcardwrapping-item item selected" data-itemvalue="0" data-itemname="giftcardwrapping">Nej</div>
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      <div class="btn btn-flat btn-block giftcardwrapping-item item " data-itemvalue="1" data-itemname="giftcardwrapping">Ja</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data` to access data attributes:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).data('itemvalue'); // = 1 || 0 depending on the clicked element
});
```

Comment: Arrh thank you :) I will accept your answear within 6min